# OpenLayers select modify feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I try to add a select box to my modify feature control in openlayers. Actually, I use a control panel with a button "modify feature", when i click on it, I can click on a feature and modify those vertices.

With the "select" control, it's possible to add a box to select features.. But I'm using this controls for other tasks.

Is there a simple way to add a selection box to the modify feature control ? (it's for select path)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible to modify many multiple features as once if that is what you are asking, but if you want to select multiple features at once you could use a bounding box like below,

```
boundingBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox({

    condition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,

    style : new ol.style.Style({
        fill : new ol.style.Fill({
            color : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
        }),
        stroke : new ol.style.Stroke({
            color : '#00FF00',
            width : 2
        }),
    })
});


//Add bounding box interaction

map.addInteraction(boundingBox);


//Add Event Listener for end of bounding box drag.Each feature, featureForPass, will be passed to    callBackFunction
boundingBox.on('boxend', function(e){
    var bbBoxExtent = boundingBox.getGeometry().getExtent() ;
    yourLayer.getSource().forEachFeatureInExtent(bbBoxExtent,callBackFunction,featureForPass)
})
```